# Converting nested for loop into its summation equivalent

Tags: summation, computer-science

What would be the correct way of converting the following for loop into its summation equivalent? Assume that $n$ is even.

```
void foo(int n) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=2; i<n; i+=2)
        for (j=0; j<n-i; j++)
            print("*");
}
```

If it were only the first for loop I was thinking of the following summation:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} 1 = \frac{n-2}{2}$$

Which does seem to produce a correct result. However, I struggle to insert the second for loop into the summation. The closest I came was:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1} 1 = \frac{n^2-3n+2}{4}$$

Which does seem to produce atleast a close estimate, yet not close enough. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summation is $\sum_i\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}1=\sum_{i} (n - i)$, where $i$ ranges over the even numbers $2, 4, \ldots, n-2$. Note that $2 + 4 + 6 + \cdots + n-2 \ne \frac12\sum_{i = 2}^{n - 2}1\ne \frac{n - 2}{2}$, it is rather $2(1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (n/2-1)) = \frac{n}2(\frac{n}2 - 1)$. Hence $\sum_i(n- i) = (\frac{n}2 - 1)n - \frac{n}2(\frac{n}2 - 1)= \frac{n}2(\frac{n}2 - 1)$.

Comment: No, I am afraid this isn't the correct answer either... For example for $n=100$ the answer should be $2450$, yours would equal $2400$

Comment: Yep, i forgot to notice that $i<n$, so the range of $i$ is $2,4,6, \ldots, n-2$ and not upro $n$. Also the range of $j$ starts from $0$ and not $1$, so the inner sum will be $n-i$ and not $n-i-1$